# lambda_handler not found in lamba_function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to deploy an AWS lamba.
Here's my folder architecture:

[image]

and my function seems to be well defined:

```
import psycopg2

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Database connection parameters
    db_params = {
    }

    # SQL query to retrieve data from a table
    select_query = "SELECT * FROM users"

    try:
        # Establish a connection to the PostgreSQL database
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**db_params)

        # Create a cursor object to interact with the database
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Execute the SQL query
        cursor.execute(select_query)

        # Fetch all rows from the result set
        rows = cursor.fetchall()

        # Process the data (print it here, but you can do anything you need)
        for row in rows:
            print(row)

    except psycopg2.Error as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
    finally:
        # Close the cursor and connection
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()
        if conn:
            conn.close()
```

even with this code I get:   "errorMessage": "Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function'"
what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your Lambda function is using this default handler value: `lambda_function.lambda_handler` to invoke your code. However, your `lambda_function.py` file is located inside a subdirectory. To resolve this issue, you have two options:

1. Either move your `lambda_function.py` file under the root directory

```
     userlambda/    
     |__lambda_function.py
```

2. Or update your handler value to point to the location of your `lambda_handler` location. Based on the attached image, your handler value will be: `lambda_function.psycopg2.lambda_function.lambda_handler`

refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html#naming) documentation to learn how to update the handler value in AWS Lambda.

Comment: I was using the windows program to compress files, which takes into account current folder. After changing that the deployment to Lambda worked fine